# Multiple splits on a single line in Python

Tags: python, split

I would like to know if there is a more compact (or Pythonic) way of doing several splits of some input string. Now I'm doing:

```
[a,bc,de] = 'a,b:c,d/e'.split(',')
[b,c] = bc.split(':')
[d,e] = de.split('/')
```

Comment: this would be cool: `[a,[b,c],[d,e]]=[a,@.split(":"),@.split("/")] = 'a,b:c,d/e'.split(',')`. don't think there's another way though

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd use the regular expression library. You don't need to use lists for unpacking, you can use tuples as below.

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'[,:/]')
a, b, c, d, e = regex.split('a,b:c,d/e')
```

Comment: what is the performance on this? i'm reading rather large files

Comment: I don't recall. Test and check if it's sufficient :)

Answer (score 1):

You're better of with regex split method probably. Don't do this, it will be crazy slow, but just to add the answer:

```
a,b,c,d,e = flatten( (x.split(',') for x in y.split(':')) for y in z.split('/')  )
```

(flatten left as an exercise for the reader (see [flatten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python)))